# Java primitive Integer.MAX_VALUE overflow

Tags: java

I am a newbee in Java and stumbled upon a such question:
What happens if a variable is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

```
System.out.println(2 * a);
System.out.println(4 * a);
```

Both give `-2` and `-4` results accordingly. Can someone explain me why this is it? I read about primitive `int` type overloading but still don't understand why I got these results?

Comment: There is a ton of information online about this. Here is one example; https://www.baeldung.com/java-overflow-underflow

Comment: I understood the integer-wraparound concept in case of adding or subtracting 1 from Integer.MAX_VALUE. But why when I multiply it gives an opposite integer number? Is it default behavior for the case when MAX_VALUE multiplied in JAVA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In binary, Integer.MAX_VALUE is

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE = 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

If you multiply this number by 2, the result is the same as shifting all bits left by 1 and adding a 0 on the right:

```
2*Integer.MAX_VALUE = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110
```

What happens if you now add 2, or `10` in binary? Thanks to overflow, all bits cancel out and you get

```
2 + 2*Integer.MAX_VALUE = 0
```

or in other words

```
2*Integer.MAX_VALUE = -2
```

There is another way to see this. In binary, -1 is all ones:

```
-1 = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111.
```

So when you multiply -1 by 2 you get:

```
2*(-1) = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110
```

Again you see 2*Integer.MAX_VALUE = -2